# union of list of dictionaries having same key value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list as shown below which contain some dictionaries.

```
dlist=[
{
    "a":1,
    "b":[1,2]
},
{
    "a":3,
    "b":[4,5]
},
{
    "a":1,
    "b":[1,2,3]
}
]
```

I want the result to be as in this form as shown below

```
dlist=[
{
    "a":1,
    "b":[1,2,3]
},
{
    "a":3,
    "b":[4,5]
}
]
```

I can solve this using multiple iteration of loops and comparison, but is there a pythonic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses a temporary defaultdict:

```python
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(set)                              # create temporary defaultdict
for d in dlist: dd[d["a"]] |= set(d["b"])          # union set(b) for each a
l = [{"a":k, "b":list(v)} for k,v in dd.items()]   # generate result list
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoMwDIbvfYrgqYUyULeL4JOUHtRUVqytaCYM57O76g4Tc0ry5//zDW96Bp9tGzo7UakWBrGSKilS@WvrpFCpzDRbJfur@Um9y8dFvXhlHnXNWDuGHprgnGnIBj@B7YcwEqBpq5cjtA0xRCjPCz4ZEqwNIyBYDwdmAYgKVfykNXxKiCc8jnWiBXPRrpYdopMHwG7gs1hhz@jkfKTgzZLpJy4i1TBaT@C27Qs)

Answer (score 0):

if My understanding is right

```
uniques, theNewList = set(), []
for d in dlist:
    cur = d["a"] # Avoid multiple lookups of the same thing
    if cur not in uniques:
        theNewList.append(d)
    uniques.add(cur)
print(theNewList)
```